# Integrating facebook SDK on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have integrate Facebook to my iPad app (the iPad app support only landscape orientation), so users can login with their Facebook credentials with the app. But when user tries to login with Facebook. the Facebook page appears on its side (one side then the other) rather than upright during the log in process. Any help on this would be great. Thanks